# Insertar ruta con espacios en visual basic

Tags: vb6

Tengo este script en visual basic

```vb
command = "powershell.exe -nologo -command D:\Google Drive\Share\Scripts\CopySaves.ps1 "

set shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

shell.Run command,0
```

El problema es que no sé cómo hacer que me coja la ruta del `.ps1` debido a que tiene un espacio. ¿Alguna idea?

Comment: prueba con esto... `D:\\Google Drive\\Share\\Scripts\\CopySaves.ps1`

Answer (score 4):

Cuando definimos una ruta con espacio en la linea de comandos, necesitamos agregar comillas dobles, agrega esas mismas comillas dobles para definir la ruta:

```
command = "powershell.exe -nologo -command ""D:\Google Drive\Share\Scripts\CopySaves.ps1"""
```